# Using boost::iterator

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, boost-iterators

I wrote a sparse vector class (see [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808437/how-to-implement-a-sparse-vector-class), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710221/is-there-a-sorted-vector-class-which-supports-insert-etc/2710744#2710744).)

I would like to provide two kinds of iterators:

The first set, the regular iterators, can point any element, whether set or unset.  If they are read from, they return either the set value or `value_type()`, if they are written to, they create the element and return the lvalue reference.  Thus, they are:

**Random Access Traversal Iterator** and **Readable** and **Writable** Iterator

The second set, the sparse iterators, iterate over only the set elements.  Since they don't need to lazily create elements that are written to, they are:

**Random Access Traversal Iterator** and **Readable** and **Writable** and **Lvalue** Iterator

I also need const versions of both, which are not writable.

I can fill in the blanks, but not sure how to use boost::iterator_adaptor to start out.

Here's what I have so far:

```
template<typename T>
class sparse_vector {
public:
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef T value_type;

private:
    typedef T& true_reference;
    typedef const T* const_pointer;
    typedef sparse_vector<T> self_type;
    struct ElementType {
        ElementType(size_type i, T const& t): index(i), value(t) {}
        ElementType(size_type i, T&& t): index(i), value(t) {}
        ElementType(size_type i): index(i) {}
        ElementType(ElementType const&) = default;
        size_type index;
        value_type value;
    };
    typedef vector<ElementType> array_type;

public:
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;

private:
    size_type                                   size_;
    mutable typename array_type::size_type      sorted_filled_; 
    mutable array_type                          data_;

// lots of code for various algorithms...

public:    
    class sparse_iterator
        : public boost::iterator_adaptor<
          sparse_iterator                   // Derived
          , typename array_type::iterator            // Base (the internal array)
          , value_type              // Value
          , boost::random_access_traversal_tag    // CategoryOrTraversal
          > {...}

    class iterator_proxy {
          ???
    };

    class iterator
        : public boost::iterator_facade<
          iterator                          // Derived
          , ?????                           // Base
          , ?????              // Value
          , boost::??????    // CategoryOrTraversal
          > {
    };
};
```

also, is this illegal?

```
typedef boost::reverse_iterator<sparse_iterator> reverse_sparse_iterator;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not sure that you really want to use `iterator_adaptor` in your case - you might want to use `iterator_facade` instead.

More thorough explanation: `iterator_adaptors` are used when you have an existing iterator (let's say `std::list<int>::iterator`) and want to reuse its behaviour for your iterator, eg. your iterator will return twice the value of what is in the list, but reuse traversal code from the original iterator. Or the other way around: you might want an iterator that will skip some of the elements in the original list, but return the values unchanged. I'm not sure whether you want to base your iterator (as in reuse code of) upon iterators of your underlying structures, but speaking for me, I wouldn't especially in the case of nonsparse iterator as you would probably want to create some proxy for the reference which means you can't use any underlying iterator `dereference()` code, and traversal is probably easy. You can, however, base your `sparse_iterator` on some iterator that iterates over actually existing elements of the array if you want.

There are problems with the proxy approach, so don't expect it to work flawlessly without going through many hoops. For one thing, the const version of the nonsparse iterator should still return `value_type()`, which means expressions like `iter->foo()` should translate to `value_type().foo()` if the corresponding entry doesn't exist. But this poses a difficulty, that `pointer_proxy::operator->()` should return something with `operator->`, preferably a pointer (definitely not `value_type()`). Which leads to the crucial question: A pointer to what? There are possibilities to solve this (for one, if you have your objects managed by `boost::shared_pointer`, you can just return a `shared_pointer` to a `new`'d instance).

For the nonsparse iterator, you need to implement:

- `class reference_proxy` with
- `reference_proxy::operator&` (that will probably return a pointer proxy)
- `reference_proxy::operator value_type&()` for const uses
- `reference_proxy::operator const value_type&()` for non-const uses
- `reference_proxy::foo()` for any `foo()` member function of value_type (otherwise expressions like `(*it).foo()` AFAIK won't work)
- `class pointer_proxy` with
- `pointer_proxy::operator*` (return a reference_proxy)
- `pointer_proxy::operator->` (do something sensible, see above)

The parameters to the iterator facade template should be:

- `Reference`: the `reference_proxy`
- `Pointer`: the `pointer_proxy`

The sparse version is simpler: If the underlying iterator is sensible (ie. matches the behaviour you want) and properly implemented, you can just omit the parameters to the `iterator_adaptor` (except for the first two), and take all the implementation.

The "doesn't compile" problem: insert `typename`.

Comment: yes, I think you're right for one of the iterators... I've updated the question.

Comment: what you're describing is exactly what I want, yes.

Comment: Thank you so much.  How do I make the sparse_iterator a readable, writable, random access iterator?  I can't just use the tag, because it's not an lvalue iterator, right?  (And what is its "Base"?)

Comment: Just use the random_access_iterator tag. The concepts proposed in the documentation of boost::iterators library, were never actually accepted, so everybody just uses the C++ standard iterator tags. You have to be prepared something (some generic algorithm) will break, sometimes, because there is not a category that could accurately describe your iterator, but most of the time, it should be OK (even more with C++0x). As for the Base for iterator_facade, there is none. It's only used with iterator_adaptor.