# Suggestions for Sparse Vector implementation without using outside libraries

Tags: c++, data-structures, sparse-matrix

I have to use a sparse vector for some things in my current project. But, since I am not in charge of the project, I can not use whatever outside libraries I want. I only have  STL and OpenCV available.

I have looked through several stackoverflow answered questions, but they either [focus on a specific approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1386075/884412), [comparison of a limited number of approaches (2) and outside libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2808437/884412) when they deal specifically with sparse vectors. There is also some excellent ideas for implementing a [sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306/https://stackoverflow.com/q/4306/884412).

What I want is *specifically a sparse vector* (the indexes will always be in 1 dimension, the data is not relevant for this question). I would like something that will not be a project on it's own to implement, but could be used for more-than-demonstrative-purposes (e.g. I want to achieve a decent speed and not too much of a memory overhead) and hopefully re-used later. The options I have considered included:

- adapting the *OpenCV* implementation of [SparseMat](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#sparsemat) to my needs
- using a `std::map` to store the values (or maybe making a very simple wrapper that would return a default value in case of indexing a zero-element)
- using a `std::vector< std::pair < int , data_type > >` where I could store the index and the data in the `std::pair` elements

Is any of these solutions better/worse for the general purpose use as a sparse vector? I know every approach to everything has it's ups and downs, but argumented suggestions on which approach to choose would be very much appreciated. Also, *recommending an approach I have not considered* would be more than welcome if anyone thinks he has a better suggestion.

---

The usage in my specific case is as follows:

- the vector will most likely not be modified after it is created (right now I don't see any need for this, but I can not guarantee 100% that it will not come up)
- a most common operation is anticipated to be *dot product* of two such vectors (so, more-or-less accessing the elements in a linear sequential way)
- only lookup I can foresee right now is (maybe) checking weather a certain element is a zero-element or not
- there will be around 500 non-zero elements expected
- in short, most of the time the sparse vector would be used as the *mathematical concept of a vector* (a multi-dimensional point) without much need to examine each coordinate separately

Still, as I have written in my original question, I would like suggestions for a general-purpose Sparse Vector implementation.

Comment: How much data you will be storing? How will the data be accessed in a linear or random way? Do you need to insert/delete in the middle? Must the memory be contiguous? Do you need to find data?

Comment: @RedX I edited the info in the question

Comment: At 500 elements i don't see the need for anything fancy unless profiling tells you so. Do as Matthieu and shabaz say and go a map and see how that works for you.

Comment: @RedX As this Sparse Vectors will be the most used datatype in my whole implementation, I started thinking about the most general good approach. Also, the number of elements is around 500 for the current implementation, and I wanted to check if there is a scalable approach that would have good performance even if the number of non-zero elements grows. In any case, the point was it all got me thinking about a most appropriate implementation, so I was mostly interested in general-purpose approach to implementing this efficiently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe `std::map` would give you the best results. `SpareseMat`, I don't know, but among the two other methods you mentioned, `std::map` will give you `O(log(n))` lookup as well as `O(log(n))` insertion and deletion. The `vector` however requires a search over all its data (so it has `O(n)` lookup). It has `O(1)` insertion, but `O(n)` removal. My guess is that you will have a lot of lookup, so most probably `std::map` is better for you.

Depending on your application, you might want to use the `vector` method during initial creation of the structure and then convert it to `map` once you start using it to get the best of both worlds (but often this is not the case, for example in the cases where you have repeating indices).

Besides `hash` which *should* give you `O(1)` everything, but in reality might not, the lookup of `O(log(n))` is the best you can hope for. You may come up with a vector that you can binary search on, or any other method based on searching for the data by comparison, but in the end they would all be `O(log(n))` so you might as well use the easy-already-done `std::map`.

---

**Update**: Based on the update on your question, that indicates that *the vector will most likely not be modified after it is created* and *a most common operation is anticipated to be dot product*, I would suggest the following:

First, use a vector of pairs as you have suggested yourself. During creation, simply `push_back` and you get `O(1)` performance.<sup>1</sup> After that, you can sort the vector. The dot product would be quite simple<sup>2</sup>:

```
int dot = 0;
unsigned int index_v1 = 0, index_v2 = 0;
while (index_v1 < v1.size() && index_v2 < v2.size())
    if (v1[index_v1].first == v2[index_v2].first)
        dot += v1[index_v1++].second * v2[index_v2++].second;
    else if (v1[index_v1].first < v2[index_v2].first)
        ++index_v1;
    else
        ++index_v2;
```

*Checking whether a certain element is a zero-element or not* would be a simple binary search, checking whether the element could be found or not (`O(log(n))` performance).

Given the fact that you would be using this structure as a point, I believe keeping it a vector would be better. You might want to later do cross product or other geometric operations.

Regarding the fact that you *may* need to insert something in the vector *every now and then*, then you would have to insert it in place (so the vector remains sorted). The performance would be `O(n)`, but since it doesn't happen often, it shouldn't be an issue.

<sup>1</sup> Unless you have millions of these vectors, `O(1)` and `O(log(n))` for `n ~= 500` should not really make any noticeable difference.

<sup>2</sup> You could definitely also use a `map` and use iterators over it to do the dot product in order of index. The performance will be the same if `std::map` uses [a threaded tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree) that lets you get to the next node in `O(1)`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. if you want to use binary search obviously, but depending on the application, it may not be a good idea, since inserting in the middle of the vector is costly. That was why I suggested using a vector during initialization (so you just `push_back`) and then later convert it to `map` for fast lookup (or sort the vector)

Comment: By side-links, I think you mean a [threaded tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree).

Comment: @larsmans, that's exactly what I meant. I couldn't remember how they named it

Answer (score 3):

**KISS**

Start with the simplest solution, that is wrap `std::map<size_t, YourData>` into a specific sparse vector structure:

```
template <typename V>
class SparseVector {
public:

private:
    std::map<size_t, V> specificValues;
    V defaultValue;
};
```

The `map` will give good default performances in all use cases (find/insert/update) and the use of a custom class means that if you ever need to change to another implementation, you will not have to change the clients sources, just recompile.